# Meaning of $\sup_{g \in G} \inf_{f \in F} \| f - g \|$ where $F$ and $G$ are functional spaces

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I don't understand the meaning of the following sentence:

*the approximation power of the function set is usually measured w.r.t (with respect to) some fixed reference class $G$* $$\sup_{g \in G} \inf_{f \in F} \| f - g \|$$

What I really don't understand is how is computed $\sup_{g \in G} \inf_{f \in F} \| f - g \|$ also because if $F = \{ax | a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ I expect the value $\sup_{g \in G} \inf_{f \in F} \| f - g \|$ to be unbounded.

Comment: If you pick some $g$, then $\inf_f  \|f-g\|$ is a measure of how 'well' $f$ (or the functions in $F$, really) can approximate $g$. Then the $\sup_g$ finds the worst case. The resulting value (which may be infinite), is a measure of how well the functions in $F$ can approximate the functions in $G$ (where the norm is the measure of 'well'). Note that if $F =G$ then the result is zero, of course.

Comment: Now it's clear. Thanks